# Is there a way to set context-params programmatically in embedded jetty?

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, web-testing

Looking at the following example of an embedded Jetty Example:
http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/running-jsf-2-on-embedded-jetty.html

The following code sample is given (below.

The author then goes on an gives an example of referring to context params in a web.xml file. eg

```
...
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

My question is - if I want to do everything in a Java class - is there a way to set context-params programmatically?

```
public class JettyRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server();

        Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        server.addConnector(connector);

        WebAppContext wac = new AliasEnhancedWebAppContext();
        wac.setContextPath("/myapp");
        wac.setBaseResource(
            new ResourceCollection(
                new String[] {"./src/main/webapp", "./target"}));
        wac.setResourceAlias("/WEB-INF/classes/", "/classes/");

        server.setHandler(wac);
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case

```
wac.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.expressionFactory",
                     "com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl")
```

will do.

Comment: how to set context-param programmatically for servlet 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
            ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
```

above code should work for you.